# Xcode invalid entitlements on very old iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, entitlements

The iOS project I've been tasked with upgrading was written in 2013, using Objective-C and iOS 7 SDK. I updated it for the simulator to work with iOS 10.3 but have run into a problem with entitlements when compiling for a device (which I think will be an issue when packaging for the store).

The error is the standard

> The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing
>   Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those
>   specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).

but as far as I remember, iOS 7 did not use entitlements in the same way (there is no entitlements file in our old repo). How do I fix it if the project was originally so old? Everything matches as far as I can tell so I don't know why it's causing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try one of that:

- Clean your certificate and make it again on Member Center
- Look your in Target> Build Settings > Code Signing > Code Signing Entitlements to confirm the code signing is correct or updated.
- Go to your Target > Capabilities. Toggle On/Off or Off/On one of the capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it was overlooking a build setting that Xcode doesn't seem to fill in.

For developing on devices at least, I had to add the path to the entitlements file in the Project section of build settings, not just the Target. This is under the "Code signing entitlements" row. After adding that entry, I was able to test on my phone again.